# How can i fetch data on a page to another, without refresing the other page?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, fetch, hbs

I'm looking to solve a problem that I'm trying to find about 3 days and I cant find it.
I already have wrote a crud application using Nodejs, Express, Handlebars, and MySQL Database. It works perfectly, but when i try to send data to other page with out refresing the i want to send the data nothing happens.

The code of home page with the crud table is here

```
{{#if removedUser}}
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  User has been removed.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{{/if}}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <h1>Users</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <a href="/adduser" type="button" class="btn btn-primary align-self-center">+ add user</a>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Credits</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-end">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    {{#each rows}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{this.id}}</th>
      <td>{{this.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.email}}</td>
      <td>{{this.credits}}</td>
      <td class="text-end">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <form action="/credits/{{this.id}}" method="post">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Credits" name="input_credits" id="input_credits"
              aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
            <div class="col-12 d-grid">
              <input class="bi bi-plus" id="post_comment" type="submit">Add</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        {{!-- <a href="/credits" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i> Add</a> --}}
        <a href="/viewuser/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i> View</a>
        <a href="/edituser/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
          Edit</a>
        {{!-- <a href="/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-person-x"></i>
          Delete</a> --}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}

    <a href="/label" type="button" class="btn btn-primary align-self-center">Label {{this.credits}}</a>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
<script src="../public/css/script.js">
```

The code of the page that i want to send data is here

```
{{#each rows}}

<div class="row">
    <span class="label label-default" id="set_input" name="set_input"> {{this.credits}}</span>

</div>
<script src="../public/css/script.js"
{{/each}}
```

And the code of the crud operations is here

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Connection Pool
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME
});

// View Users
exports.view = (req, res) => {
  // User the connection
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE status = "active"', (err, rows) => {
    // When done with the connection, release it
    if (!err) {
      let removedUser = req.query.removed;
      res.render('home', { rows, removedUser });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}

// Find User by Search
exports.find = (req, res) => {
  let searchTerm = req.body.search;
  // User the connection
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?', ['%' + searchTerm + '%', '%' + searchTerm + '%'], (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('home', { rows });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}

exports.form = (req, res) => {
  res.render('add-user');
}

// Add new user
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, email, credits, comments } = req.body;
  let searchTerm = req.body.search;

  // User the connection
  connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, credits = ?, comments = ?', [first_name, last_name, email, credits, comments], (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('add-user', { alert: 'User added successfully.' });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}


// Edit user
exports.edit = (req, res) => {
  // User the connection
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('edit-user', { rows });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}


// Update User
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, email, credits, comments } = req.body;
  // User the connection
  connection.query('UPDATE user SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, credits = ?, comments = ? WHERE id = ?', [first_name, last_name, email, credits, comments, req.params.id], (err, rows) => {

    if (!err) {
      // User the connection
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
        // When done with the connection, release it
        
        if (!err) {
          res.render('edit-user', { rows, alert: `${first_name} has been updated.` });
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}

// Delete User
exports.delete = (req, res) => {

  // Delete a record

  // User the connection
  connection.query('DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {

    if(!err) {
      let removedUser = encodeURIComponent('User succesefully removed');
      res.redirect('/?removed=' + removedUser);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);

  });

  // Hide a record

  // connection.query('UPDATE user SET status = ? WHERE id = ?', ['removed', req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
  //   if (!err) {
  //     let removedUser = encodeURIComponent('User successeflly removed.');
  //     res.redirect('/?removed=' + removedUser);
  //   } else {
  //     console.log(err);
  //   }
  //   console.log('The data from beer table are: \n', rows);
  // });

}

// View Users
exports.viewall = (req, res) => {

  // User the connection
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('view-user', { rows });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });

}

exports.label = (req, res) => {

  console.log("GOOOODDDD")
  const credits = req.body.phone;
  const set_input = req.body.set_input;
  connection.query('SELECT credits FROM user WHERE id = 4', [req.params.id], (err,rows) => {
    if(!err){
      set_input == credits;
      res.render('label', {rows})
    }else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}




exports.credits = (req, res) => {
  const credits = req.body.input_credits*100;
  // User the connection
  connection.query('UPDATE user SET credits = ? WHERE id = ?', [credits, req.params.id], (err, rows) => {

    if (!err) {
      // User the connection
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
        // When done with the connection, release it
        
        if (!err) {
          
          res.redirect('/');
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is you need to call   `event.preventDefault()` when calling  your form onSubmit event.

[Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)